# Laravel 5.1 - Showing Comments on Specific Page

Tags: php, laravel-5

**Edit3: Could a reason be because both controllers are leading to the same page?**

**Edit2: Still not working after the answers I got.**

**Edit: Error one is solved, now I'm getting:**

> Undefined variable: project (View:
>   /var/www/resources/views/pages/showProject.blade.php)

Can this be because both variables are leading to the same page? The projects variable was working perfectly before the comment system.

```
public function index()
{
    $projects = Project::all();

    return view('pages.projects', compact('projects'));
}
```

Project variable declare.

I'm trying to get my comments from my database to show on a specific 'project page' in the laravel 5 project I'm working on. The idea is that the user can add art projects and other users can comment on them, but whenever I try to visit the page I get

> Undefined variable: comments (View:
>   /var/www/resources/views/pages/showProject.blade.php)

This is my controller

```
public function index()
{
  $comments = Comment::all();

  return view('pages.showProject', compact('comments'));
}

public function store()
  {
    $input = Request::all();
    $comment = new Comment;
    $comment->body = $input['body'];
    $comment->project_id = $input['project_id'];
    $comment->user_id = Auth::user()->id;
    $comment->save();
    return redirect('projects/'.$input['project_id']);

}
```

These are my routes

```
// add comment
Route::post('projects/{id}','CommentController@store');

// show comments
Route::post('projects/{id}','CommentController@index');
```

And my view

```
 @if (Auth::check())

    <article> <!--Add comment -->

        <br/>
        {!! Form::open() !!}
        {!! form::text('body', null, ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}

        <br/>

        {!! Form::Submit('Post Comment', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary form-control']) !!}
        {!! Form::hidden('project_id', $project->id) !!}


        {!! Form::close() !!}
        <br/>

    </article>

    <article>

        @foreach ($comments as $comment)

            <article>

                <p>Body: {{ $comment->body }}</p>
                <p>Author: {{ $comment->user->name }}</p>

            </article>


        @endforeach

    </article>
    @else
    <p>Please log in to comment</p>
   @endif
```

The Model

```
class Comment extends Model
{
    //comments table in database
    protected $guarded = [];

    // user who has commented
    public function author()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User','user_id');
    }

    // returns post of any comment
    public function post()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Project','project_id');
    }

    public function comments()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Comment');
    }

    public $timestamps = false;
}
```

Is there any way I can solve this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: try `return view('pages.showProject', array('comments'=>$comments));`

Comment: 'Expression result unused' & 'unreachable statement' on the $comments part of the return view. I'll update the OP with my model.

Comment: Also `Route::post('projects/{id}','CommentController@index');` should be `Route::get('projects/','CommentController@index');`//the id is not used and you are using GET not POST

Comment: Ok, that was my bad. I replaced that and now the error says 'Undefined variable: project (View: /var/www/resources/views/pages/showProject.blade.php)'. Can this be because both the comments and projects variables are leading to the same page?

Comment: Add the project variable as an associative array in the view like for the comments `(array('project'=>Project::where('id', '=', $id)->firstOrFail()))` and in the controller get the $id from the request(`function index($id)`, change route with the id in the url(`Route::get('projects/{id}','CommentController@index');`)

Comment: I think the relationship is wrong. Check my answer.

Comment: Added declaration for projects to OP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to empty the show in the commentsController and only use it for saving the comments. For showing them I made an extra function in my projectsController. It ended up being this;

```
 public function show($id)
    {
    $project = Project::findOrFail($id)->load("User");

    $input = Request::all();

    //-----------------------DB-----------------------------//
    $project_comments = DB::table('comments')
        ->select('body', 'name')
        ->where('project_id', '=', $id)
        ->join('users', 'users.id', '=', 'user_id')
        ->get();
    //-----------------------DB-----------------------------//

    return view('pages.showProject', ['project' => Project::findOrFail($id), 'comments' => $project_comments]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to make sure that you are aliasing your 'Comment' model in your controller. This is done with the `use` statement.

```
use App\Comment;

class CommentController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
      $comments = Comment::all();

      return view('pages.showProject', compact('comments'));
    }
}
```

Second, you will need to change your route for showing comments from a POST request to a GET request. At the moment you are making identical routes and furthermore GET is the correct request type for retrieving data.

```
Route::get('projects/{id}','CommentController@index');
```

Third, you are referencing a $project variable in your view, but never passing it in from the controller. That needs to reference something.

Comment: Both of these things have been corrected. Made an edit at the bottom of the OP with the results.

Comment: Ah okay, make sure you define that $project variable for your view as well. Didn't realize it was being answered in the comments.

Comment: The project variable is defined as it was working before I added the comments. I prefer the question being answered in the answer section as well.

Answer (score 0):

I think your relationship is wrong. Try this:

**Comment model:**

```
class Comment extends Model
{
    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }
}
```

**User model:**

```
class User extends Model
{
    public function comments()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Comment');
    }
}
```

In the view you can use:

```
@foreach($comments as $comment)
    <p>{{ $comment->user->name }}</p>
@endforeach
```

Comment: Corrected it. Same issue has the edit on the OP. Thanks for the fixes!

Comment: why don't you use the $comment->id instead of $project->id?

Comment: Every project page has a specific id linked to the project + the comments have to be unique per project.